# EMR -spark maximizeResourceAllocation default value in EMR 6.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

What is default value of `maximizeResourceAllocation` in EMR if we dont specify it while creating the EMR cluster?
I have gone through various AWS docs  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html

But couldn't find its value.
The problem is we are not setting `spark.executor.memory` settings in our spark job.But by default this is set to 18G. I think this is set based on core or task node type.
I tried setting this to lower level but it is still 18G. What could be possible reason?

I am assuming problem lies with `maximizeResourceAllocation` settings. I am very curious to know its default value. We dont use this parameter in EMR configuration

Comment: This default of ~18GiB for spark.executor.memory is not related to the maximizeResourceAllocation feature. EMR provides default values for spark.executor.memory/cores based on the CORE instance type, and ~18GiB is the value used for "high-memory" instance type series like r and i series. Different instance type series, such as m and c series, have different default executor memory/core values.

Comment: The fact that you are seeing behavior where it does not honor your settings is definitely unexpected though. Would you be able to share more details, such as how exactly you are trying to configure these values?

Comment: i am submitting spark jobs in cluster mode via livy API and passing `spark.executor.memory` there

Comment: by the way, is there any documentation which i can refer about default executor/core of different instance types?